# how to use 3 child in firebase for retrieving the value of child of child

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

How to use 3 child in firebase for retrieving the value of child of child using android studio?

[image]

I need to get values of mod1,mod2...

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: As is see it you have two options:  
1. Use array data set for mode and retrieve the arrays of mods per user.
2. Keep reference for each mod and every time you need a mod you need to query it.

Comment: Sounds feasible. Did you try anything already? If so, please show the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it's quite useful). If you didn't try anything yet, it's probably best to start with the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start), its [codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) developers, or one of the many tutorials out there.